# I repeatedly get an error about unmet dependencies for adobe-flashplugin while trying to install anything

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, flash

Whenever I try to install anything I repeatedly get the error below and then the installation stops. Moreover I also get the error that I have to fix the Ubuntu software center but I cant due this same error.

For example, when I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk:
        Depends: adobe-flashplugin (= 1:20160310.1-0ubuntu 0.12.04.1) 
                 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages 
   (or specify a solution)
```

Comment: Does the action suggested in the error message fix things? `sudo apt-get install -f`? If not, try `sudo apt-get update` before.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for error messages in the future - you can copy lines in the terminal into your question as an edit to get error messages made available here for us to review and helps those of us using mobile devices to access Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I've already faced similar problems and I figured that in most cases the only thing you have to do is

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If that doesn't help, you should edit file /var/lib/dpkg/status and delete whole blocks of broken packages. Then repeat first two commands and that should fix it.

Comment: its still giving me this error

Answer (score -1):

Try to start aptitude

```
sudo aptitude
```

aptitude should also determines the problems and often proposes a solutions with can be applied pressing the "!"-key. Have a look in the bottom line of aptitude. There should be some hints in a red backgrounded line.

Often the solution is to remove the incomplete installed packages.